# How do I get the last point of CGContext in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgcontext

I'm working on a custom progress bar and I want to get the last point of `CGContext` because I want to add an image to current state.

This is my code:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGPoint center = CGPointMake(rect.size.width/2, rect.size.height/2);
float minSize = MIN(rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
float lineWidth = _strokeWidth;
if(lineWidth == -1.0) lineWidth = minSize*_strokeWidthRatio;
float radius = (minSize-lineWidth)/2;
float endAngle = M_PI*(self.value*2);

//what should i do here
//_pont.center = CGPointMake

CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, center.x, center.y);
CGContextRotateCTM(ctx, -M_PI*0.5);


CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, lineWidth);
CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapRound);

// "Full" Background Circle:
CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
CGContextAddArc(ctx, 0, 0, radius, 0, 2*M_PI, 0);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [_color colorWithAlphaComponent:0.1].CGColor);
CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

// Progress Arc:
CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
CGContextAddArc(ctx, 0, 0, radius, 0, endAngle, 0);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [_color colorWithAlphaComponent:0.9].CGColor);
CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to get?  The last endAngle?  Whatever you're trying to get, why not declare an instance variable e.g. lastEndAngle, initialize it in your init method and reset it (lastEndAngle = endAngle) at the end of your drawRect Code.  BTW, you should be careful about using float where you need CGFloat.  Depending on your system (32 bit or 64 bit) there may be a difference.

Comment: i want to get current point to set my imageView center to current state

Answer (score 1):

You have to use CGContextGetPathCurrentPoint, but you have to call it before you clear the path by calling stroke or fill. So look at the following playground and see what the value returned by CGContextGetPathCurrentPoint return varies by when you call it.

```
import CoreGraphics
import UIKit

let lineWidth = CGFloat(10)
let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
let size = CGSizeMake(100, 100)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

let center = CGPointMake(rect.size.width/2, rect.size.height/2);
let minSize = fmin(rect.size.width, rect.size.height);

let radius = (minSize-10)/2;
let endAngle = CGFloat(M_PI*(20.0*2))

CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, center.x, center.y);
CGContextRotateCTM(ctx, CGFloat(-M_PI*0.5));


CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, lineWidth);
CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, CGLineCap.Round);

// "Full" Background Circle:
CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
CGContextAddArc(ctx, 0, 0, radius, 0, CGFloat(2*M_PI), 0);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, UIColor.greenColor().CGColor);
var  endPoint = CGContextGetPathCurrentPoint(ctx)
CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
endPoint = CGContextGetPathCurrentPoint(ctx)

// Progress Arc:
CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
CGContextAddArc(ctx, 0, 0, radius, 0, endAngle, 0);
endPoint = CGContextGetPathCurrentPoint(ctx)
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, UIColor.redColor().CGColor);
CGContextStrokePath(ctx);


CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);

let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's all simple geometry.

With context transformation matrix from your `drawRect:` code, you should use:

```
CGPoint lastPoint = CGPointMake(radius * cos(endAngle), radius * sin(endAngle));
```

After reset or before setup CTM, you should use:

```
//Replace "what should i do here" comment with following code:
CGPoint lastPoint = CGPointZero;
lastPoint.x = center.x + radius * cos(endAngle - M_PI * 0.5);
lastPoint.y = center.y + radius * sin(endAngle - M_PI * 0.5);
```

Also, second solution will work outside of `drawRect:` implementation.